# Permutations of a set of numbers with binary operators

Tags: algorithm, optimization, operators, permutation, parentheses

Let's given a set of numbers. By inserting the elements of another set which consists of binary operators between them and grouping the expressions with balanced parentheses, find all possible permutations.

The challenging part of the question is the commutative behaviour of some binary operators. For instance, in case the expression `(2 + 3) * 5` has found, then there's no need for computing the expressions `(3 + 2) * 5`, or `5 * (2 + 3)`, or `5 * (3 + 2)` because of the commutative identity of the operators `+` and `*`. Their former equivalents need to be ignored.

Another aspect of this question is the grouping via balanced parentheses. Given `2 * 3 + 5`, the grouping `2 * (3 + 5)` gives a distinct result but `(2 * 3) + 5`, or even `(((2 * 3)) + 5)` just creates duplications.

Are there any algorithms to cope with these type of issues? How can one find all the permutations of expressions with optimizing the commutative behaviour of binary operators and filtering the parentheses that result with duplications?

Comment: You might want to google `common subexpression elimination`, which is a related field within compiler design. I believe the most common approach there is to encode the expression in a directed acyclic graph (dag).

Comment: You can also consider converting every expression to a standard form, e.g. replacing `a * b + c` by `(a * b) + c`, replacing `((x))` by `(x)`, sorting sums and products by some criteria (number and size of primitive operands inside their parentheses, etc.). If there is an algorithm to find a unique representative for every given equivalence class, the resulting problem to compare and reduce redundant expressions looks more or less trivial.